# Upgrading from Entity Framework 6.2 to 6.3.0 in NuGet

Tags: visual-studio

Entity Framework 6.3.0 was published on 2019 Sep 23. I have two projects in my solution that were using 6.2 and I tried to upgrade to 6.3.0 via NuGet.

One project called `DatabaseInterface` has an output type of "class library". The other project outputs a "console application".

When I run the upgrade from NuGet the following error happens for the project that is the class library.

```
An error occurred while applying transformation to 'App.config' in
project 'DatabaseInterface' No element in the source document matches
'/configuration/configSections/section[@name='entityFramework']'
```

This project, called `DatabaseInterface` does not even have an `App.config` file so the error is referring to a file that does not exist. This project has a `packages.config` file.

Published problems with a similar error are related to web projects so they are probably not closely relevant to my problem. What is the solution to this problem?

Context: `Visual Studio 2017 Community`, `Visual Studio 2019 Community`, `Windows 10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninstall 6.2 and then install 6.3. This seems to cause the automatic deletion of `packages.config` and there will be no error associated with `App.config` nor will there be the creation of that file. Subsequent builds do not seem to require the presence of `packages.config`.

Comment: Uninstalling it and deleting the `App.config` did the trick for me.